# How to insert json data into postgresql bytea column?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to insert json data to a column in postgres(latest version) database with column data type as bytea but I get the below error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea
Line 258: VALUES ('DUMMY', 2100, '{"serviceId":"Y","continuedService":"....
```

Here is the ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE datamine
( 
  ine varchar(10) not null,
  essaykey integer not null,
  JSONDATA bytea
)
```

Here is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO datamine VALUES('DUMMY', 2100, '{"serviceId":"Y","continuedService":"E345"}')
```

I have to use bytea only as per the previous code and architecture. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why store JSON data in a `bytea`  column. You should be using `jsonb` instead

Comment: As per previous architecture and plan we have to stick to bytea only. But those people who worked previously are not part of the team now.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. You basically lose all benefits of the `jsonb` type if you convert the text value to a binary value each time you write it and convert it back to a string/json each time you read it. You lose the ability to index the data any you will be doing constant casting back and forth. Don't stick to the errors of previous people. But if you really want to make your life way harder than it needs to be, you have to convert the string to a bytea (providing a proper encoding). See the ` convert_to ()` function. But I can only repeat that this is a really bad idea.

Comment: `'{"serviceId":"Y","continuedService":"E345"}'::bytea`, though as mentioned this is not a good idea.

Comment: Please choose a better question title.